# Grafana Loki-2.5.0 log retention period is not working

Tags: grafana-loki

I upgraded my Loki deployment in kebernet from Loki-2.4.0 to Loki-2.5.0. 
But after upgrading, old chunks are not getting deleted, so they fill up the filesystem.

It looks like the retention period is not working.

I am trying to configure a 7-day retention period for Loki.

Can someone please help me configure the retention period in Loki-2.5.0 ?

My configuration -

```
auth_enabled: false
server:
  http_listen_port: 3100
  grpc_server_max_recv_msg_size: 67108864
  grpc_server_max_send_msg_size: 67108864
ingester:
  lifecycler:
    address: 127.0.0.1
    ring:
      kvstore:
        store: inmemory
      replication_factor: 1
    final_sleep: 0s
  chunk_idle_period: 15m
  chunk_retain_period: 30s
  max_transfer_retries: 0
  wal:
    enabled: true
    dir: /loki/wal
schema_config:
  configs:
    - from: 2021-02-01
      store: boltdb
      object_store: filesystem
      schema: v11
      index:
        prefix: index_
        period: 24h
      chunks:
        prefix: chunks_
        period: 24h
storage_config:
  boltdb:
    directory: /loki/index
  filesystem: 
    directory: /loki/chunks
    
    
limits_config:
  enforce_metric_name: false
  reject_old_samples: true
  reject_old_samples_max_age: 72h
  ingestion_rate_mb: 32
  creation_grace_period: 30m
  max_entries_limit_per_query: 50000
chunk_store_config:
  max_look_back_period: 0s
table_manager:
  retention_deletes_enabled: true
  retention_period: 168h
```

Comment: My Loki-2.5.0 configuration -

Answer (score 1):

try to configure limits_config.retention_period: 168h